# define a function to check if a list of elements is palindrome and returns a list

Tags: python, list, function, boolean, palindrome

I have to do the following:

Define a function called isSymmetricalVec that takes a list of elements, checks if each element in a list is palindrome, then returns their results in a list. For example, given `["1441", "Apple", "radar", "232", "plane"]` the function returns `[TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE]`.

I wrote the following code but I'm stuck at the point where I cannot return the result in a list.

```py
def isSymmetricalVec(myList): 
    
    for myString in myList:
        
        myList = []
   
        mid = (len(myString)-1)//2
        start = 0
        last = len(myString)-1
        flag = 0
  
        while(start<mid): 
   
            if (myString[start]== myString[last]): 
              
                start += 1
                last -= 1
              
            else: 
                flag = 1
                break; 
              
        if flag == 0: 
            print(bool(1)) 
        else: 
            print(bool(0)) 

# Enter a list of strings to check whether it is symmetrical or not 
myList = ["12321", "12345", "madam", "modem"]
isSymmetricalVec(myList)
```

My function returns the following but the result is not in a list format:

```
True
False
True
False
```

How can I modify my code to return a result in a list format?

Comment: `.append` to `myList` instead of just `print`ing

Comment: Do you know how to return values from functions?

Comment: Also, `bool(1)` and `flag = 1` is very "C-like". Just use `True` and `False` directly

Answer (score 0):

Your function is actually not **returning** anything. What you see are only being **printed** and not **returned**.

You would want to keep each answer in a `list` like this.

```
def isSymmetricalVec(myList):
    list_of_answers = []
    
    for myString in myList:
        ...
  
        while(start<mid): 
            ...
              
        if flag == 0: 
            print(bool(1))
            list_of_answers.append(True)
        else: 
            print(bool(0)) 
            list_of_answers.append(False)

    return list_of_answers
```

This way your answers are printed and returned.

Finally, you would need a variable to hold the **returned** `list`.

```
# Enter a list of strings to check whether it is symmetrical or not 
myList = ["12321", "12345", "madam", "modem"]
list_of_answers = isSymmetricalVec(myList)
```

Answer (score 0):

You function should `return` value instead of printing it.
Created an empty list `new_list` and `appended` result to it.

```
def isSymmetricalVec(myList):
    new_lst = []
    for myString in myList:

        mid = (len(myString) - 1) // 2
        start = 0
        last = len(myString) - 1
        flag = 0

        while (start < mid):

            if (myString[start] == myString[last]):

                start += 1
                last -= 1

            else:
                flag = 1
                break;

        if flag == 0:
            new_lst.append(True)
        else:
            new_lst.append(False)

    return new_lst
        # Enter a list of strings to check whether it is symmetrical or not
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def isSymmetricalVec(myString): 

    mid = (len(myString)-1)//2
    start = 0
    last = len(myString)-1
    flag = 0

    while(start<mid): 

        if (myString[start]== myString[last]): 
            
            start += 1
            last -= 1
            
        else: 
            flag = 1
            break; 
            
    if flag == 0: 
        return True
    else: 
        return False


test = ["1221", "madam", "hello world"]
    
final = [isSymmetricalVec(i) for i in test]
print(final)
```

I rewrote the code a bit and this would be my solution. It retains the original functionality and is stylish as well as efficient. It also makes the original function more flexible and makes it easily migratable.

Answer (score 0):

Your function doesn't return anything, just printing values.
There is a good way to shorten your algorithm with python `slices`. Also this function **returns** list of boolean objects.

```
from math import ceil, floor

def isSymmetricalVec(myList):
    list_of_answers = []
    for string in myList:
        strLength = len(string)
        #There is a string palindrome check
        if string[:floor(strLength//2)] == string[ceil(strLength/2):][::-1]:
            toAppend = True
        else:
            toAppend = False
        list_of_answers.append(toAppend)
    
    return list_of_answers
```

> It is worth adding that it's better to use `True` and `False` instead of `bool(1)` and `bool(0)`.

#### An example:

```
>>> isSymmetricalVec(['11211', 'AbbA', '12f23'])
>>> [True, True, False]
```